# I can't boot Linux Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

As title states - I have installed it (my first system is windows, windows is on disk C, linux on disk E), I am pretty sure I did it correctly, but when I turn on computer it just launches windows automatically.
Basically windows can't see linux (I can't even see disk E in my computer in windows anymore), and I think windows has priority over linux, and thus I can't launch linux.
Am I right?
I can try linux from pendrive, by pressing "assist" button on my laptop (sony vaio) when it's turned off, or by holding f11 while turning on computer, but I just can't launch the one I installed on my computer.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are disk C and disk E separate disks or just separate partitions? If separate disks try setting disk E as the first hard drive.

Comment: I think you need to hold Shift while booting to bring up the Grub menu.

Comment: Partitions, shift doesn't work.

Comment: If you boot the computer usin your Live drive can you see your Ubuntu partition in Disks?

Comment: Yes, I can see it.

Comment: If you can see the Ubuntu partition, and it is occupied, You did not install the bootloader in the right place, It should have overwritten the Windows bootloader. What instructions did you use to install Ubuntu? Did you use `Something else`?

Comment: Yeah, actually I installed bootloader in the wrong place by mistake, problem is solved now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enter Windows, exec cmd as *administrator* (important) and type:

bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

then reboot! Good luck!

Comment: Uhh... And what do I do if it didn't work? :|

Comment: enter the bios and try change the boot order in favor of grub...

Comment: I didn't really have such option in bios. But nevermind, actually I installed bootloader in wrong place by mistake, problem is solved now. Thanks